# Error U1077 return code

Tags: c++, qt, static

I get an error when I try to compile QT. I compile it with the source in static with openssl. I use this tutorial to make the "build" script

```
C:\Qt\5.8_Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase>configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix C:\Qt\5.8_Static\5.8.0 -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -openssl-linked -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
Please wait while bootstrapping configure ...
<srcbase> = C:/Qt/5.8_Static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase
<outbase> = C:/Qt/5.8_Static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.    

    cl -c -Yc -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -W3 -GR -EHsc -w34100 -w34189 -wd4577   -D
UNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_BUILD_CONFIGURE -DQT_U
SE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_VERSION_STR=\"5.8.0\" -DQT_VERSION_MAJOR=5 -DQT_VERSION_M
INOR=8 -DQT_VERSION_PATCH=0 -I"..\..\include" -I"..\..\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\
include\QtCore\5.8.0" -I"..\..\include\QtCore\5.8.0\QtCore" -I"C:\Qt\5.8_Static\
src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\tools\shared" -I"C:\Qt\5.8_Static\
src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fpconfigu
re_pch.pch -Foconfigure_pch.obj -TP C:\Qt\5.8_Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensourc
e-src-5.8.0\qtbase\tools\configure\configure_pch.h
configure_pch.h
c:\qt\5.8_static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\include\qtcore\..
/../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(45): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le
fichier include : 'type_traits' : No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : code retour '0x2'
Stop.
```